# IIS Application suddenly fails with 503 response but without event log entries

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

In our company we have an ASP.NET 7 Razor Pages app hosted with IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016. We have multiple instances of this software at multiple plants of the company. Only on one server we have from time to time (1-2 times a week) the issue, that the application from one moment to the other just returns "This service is unavailable" with a 503 response. It seems the application pool is stopped, but when looking in IIS, it is still running. Furthermore, hosted services tht do work periodically continue to work because we still see log entries from them. So it seems to be an IIS issue.

The web site will work properly again only after manually recycling the application pool. Therafter everything is fine at first, automatic recycling after 29 hours is also working. But then, after another random period of 2-5 days, it will fail again with the 503 response.

Windows event log does not contain any information. There are no errors or warnings when the web app gets stuck. Only when we manually recycle the app pool, there is the entry from source "IIS AspNetCore Module V2" that reports the shutdown and thereafter the successfull restart.

As said, the exact same software with the same version is working well on other servers. On the failing server, there are also other web applications, that do not have the same problem. The failing software used to work properly for more than 3 years and started to behave strange suddenly some weeks ago without any apparant changes.

The app pool's identity is ok and not blocked. The app pool is set up the same way as all the other app pools. We've double checked all properties.

The numbers of requests made to IIS before the web app fails is normal, we've checked those logs as well.

Our internal application logging that logs all handled exceptions does not output anything.

Server resources are also OK, CPU load only 10-25%t, 7GB free memory available.

We are happy for every suggestion where we could continue to search because we have run out of ideas.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code 503 responses are not only generated when an application pool is shut down, but also when concurrent requests exceed the limit. The best way I can think of is to analyze the actual requests being handled when the issue occurs again, but that needs a tool like performance profiler, or hang dump analysis. Both troubleshooting approaches are not trivial, and you need to hire a consultant or a Microsoft support ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting the intermittent issue you describe can be challenging. When the server hangs or crashes, it is usually necessary to capture the server's thread stack (Thread Dump) for subsequent analysis.

The debug diagnostic tool (DebugDiag) can be a lifesaver. You can refer to: [IIS Application Pool Crash and Debug Diag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/parvez/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag). It creates and analyzes IIS crash dumps. After seeing the call stack, you may be able to figure out the cause of the crash.

But analyzing dump files is a complicated process, So I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.